# Xcode NSFetchRequest Not Executing

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a bit of a conundrum on my hands.

I am doing a *NSFetchRequest* to my SQLite database in xcode and the query i am running is pretty simple:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
[[context undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];
NSError *error = nil;
NSEntityDescription *entity = nil;

entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Workbook" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language == 'English'" ]];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"sequence" ascending:YES]]];

NSLog(@"----- Request Print out: %@",request);
NSArray *subjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The first time this code works it executes fine.

I then change my view and perform another fetch and insert in a different part of the app navigate back to the view that hosts this code and the code then fails to execute:

```
[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The app doesn't freeze, or crash and no error messages are displayed on the console. I have even enabled logging for my sql db fetches and i can see the sql for the request is never executed the 2nd time.

The fetch request when logged looks like:

```
<NSFetchRequest: 0x20063120> (entity: Workbook; predicate: (language == "English"); sortDescriptors: (("(sequence, ascending, compare:)")); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

This is identical to when the code executes the first time and when it executes the second so the request itself can't be the issue.

Is it possible my db is locked some how after the previous operations?

Could the app loose connectivity with the DB, seen as the DB isn't receiving the request?

I have left the app to see if anything happens but it just sits indefinitely...

I have tried all the profiling etc that i can think of but cannot find anything obvious like leaks or weird processes happening.

All help appreciated

Comment: if you use undo management, you need to call `processPendingChanges` on the context before disabling the undo manager ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html)). what do you mean by "fail to execute"? does it return nil or an empty array?

Comment: @DanShelly it doesn't return anything the code stops executing at `[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` and the array doesn't even get populated... Why would i want to use undo manager? Are you simply suggesting disabling it?

Comment: this line: `[[context undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];` suggest you use undo management, and should be preceeded by `processPendingChanges`. to not use undo management, simple set the undo manager to `nil` uppon creation. does "stops executing" mean halting (== app freez)? do you use threading with the same context?

Comment: @DanShelly i will give it a go. let you know my results. "stops executing" means the app freezes on that fetch statement every time no matter if i insert 6 lines to db or on 1. 

I do use threading in as i use _MBProgressHUD_ this view is in a tab bar so i can see the other tabs thread when i start debugging. Can't see any other random threads in debug (step thru) mode. I also tried to run the code with no _MBProgressHUD_ and it still froze at the same place in the code.

Comment: P.S. I canged my context to allow undo management and added in `[context processPendingChanges];` but still no luck.

Complete code for class [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bi2qwh1ke3vj16n/3wknO_gog0)

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided, and looking at the `MBProgressHUD` source, it is clear you are accessing your context from different threads then the ones it was created on (thread confinment breach) and not using a private queue context.

the progress HUD is detatching a new thread for the selector execution, while you context is probably defined as a "confinment" or "main thread" concurrency.

The first time, the context is created on a detached thread (T1), and when you get back to the view controller again, it is used on another detached thread (T2).

Since I realy don't know `MBProgressHUD`, my advice to you is to find a method that perform the selector you call on the main thread while the progress HUD is doing its thing.
Or, perform this loading on a temporary context (one that will be created in the detached thread and disposed on the ditached thread) that will then export the results to the main context/thread.

**CoreData does not allow passing of managed objects or managed contexts between threads**

A quick fix would be:
(this solution is importing the data as dictionaries on a temporary confined context)

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;
context.undoManager = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSEntityDescription *entity = nil;

entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Workbook" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language == 'English'" ]];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor     alloc]initWithKey:@"sequence" ascending:YES]]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[/*the properties you need*/]];

NSLog(@"----- Request Print out: %@",request);
NSArray *subjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
//you can now pass subjects between thread as it contains 
//dictionaries and not managed objects
```

Comment: I will give this a go on wednesday... I can confirm it looks like a threading issue because if i comment on MBProgressHUD in both views the app seems to run smoothy with no issues... First time i have had an issue with MBProgressHUD as i have used it in other projects with no issue...